# How to align listed bullet point text?

Tags: html, css, html-lists

I have a bullet list with an image as the bullet point and have it coded like as shown in the snippet:

```css
li::before {
  content: "";
  display: inline-block;
  height: 15px;
  width: 15px;
  background-size: contain;
  background-image: url('https://adp-com-prod.es.ad.adp.com/-/media/apps/wfn/images/rs_email_checklisticon-bullet.png?rev=f7aed74…&hash=2EB10B8B4C4FCB24BC37B1E501219BBB');
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  margin-right: 7px;
  background-position: center center;
  vertical-align: middle;
}
ul {
  padding-left: 0;
  list-style: none;
}
```

```html
       <ul class="voe-list">
                <li>
                  <strong>Simplicity.</strong> this is bullet number one with a longer sentence so it goes on the second line. Stay tuned for bullet number 2.
                </li>
                <li>
                  <strong>Compliance.</strong>this is bullet number one with a longer sentence so it goes on the second line.Stay tuned for bullet number 3. 
                </li>
                <li>
                  <strong>Flexibility.</strong>this is bullet number one with a longer sentence so it goes on the second line.Stay tuned for bullet number 4.
                </li>
              </ul>
```

As you can see each bullet copy is not aligned and the second line starts where the check mark starts. any way we can do it so it aligned with the first word of the first line? I could add padding-left or margin-left but wanted to see if there was another way.

In the default unordered list, it does align since the list-style lies in the  tag (see screenshot)

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I understand what you're trying to do, but `li::before` is not how you change the bullet point. With what you have, all you're doing is adding the image at the front of every `<li>`, so it actually *is* aligning correctly.

To fix it, get rid of that `li::before` style entirely. You can change the bullet of a `<ul>` using the `list-style` property and `url()`.

```
ul {
  /* padding-left: 0; */
  /* list-style: none; */
  list-style: url('https://adp-com-prod.es.ad.adp.com/-/media/apps/wfn/images/rs_email_checklisticon-bullet.png?rev=f7aed74…&hash=2EB10B8B4C4FCB24BC37B1E501219BBB');
}
```

Does that fix your problem?

Answer (score 0):

If you add negative margin to counteract the margin you've added you get the desired result.

(I added a bullet image from the web so you can see the list layout is working how you are intending)

```css
li::before {
  content: "";
  display: inline-block;
  height: 15px;
  width: 15px;
  background-size: contain;
  background-image: url('data:image/png;base64,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');
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  margin-right: 7px;
  margin-left: -25px;
  background-position: center center;
  vertical-align: middle;
}
ul {
  padding-left: 0;
  list-style: none;
  margin-left: 25px;
}
```

```html
<ul class="voe-list">
                <li>
                  <strong>Simplicity.</strong> this is bullet number one with a longer sentence so it goes on the second line. Stay tuned for bullet number 2.
                </li>
                <li>
                  <strong>Compliance.</strong>this is bullet number one with a longer sentence so it goes on the second line.Stay tuned for bullet number 3. 
                </li>
                <li>
                  <strong>Flexibility.</strong>this is bullet number one with a longer sentence so it goes on the second line.Stay tuned for bullet number 4.
                </li>
              </ul>
```